# Google Sheets, using Countifs to count number of values in a range, and match another cell's value

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Working on a Google Spreadsheet, seems to be behaving differently from excel.
This spreadsheet is integrated from a Google form, responses have a date, and a username.
What I am trying to do is count the number of entries between two dates, and submitted by a certain user.
I.e. the sheet looks like this:
  A      B            C
Timestamp  User         User Names
2/2/2015   Joe Jones    Joe Jones
2/12/2015  Steve Ahn    Steve Ahn
2/15/2015  Joe Jones
3/3/2015   Joe Jones
3/4/2015   Steve Ahn

I want to count the number of entries for Joe Jones between 2/14/2015 and 3/4/2015 i.e. return the result of 2 here.
Here is what I have so far:
=COUNTIFS(A1:A15,">="&I1,A1:A15,"<="&I2, B2:B15, C1)
But it throws an error "Array Arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size"
Each bit works as a countifs on its own.
Thanks!

Comment: Looking at it here I realized what the problem is.  The correct formula is:

Comment: =COUNTIFS(A2:A15,">="&I1,A2:A15,"<="&I2, B2:B15, F2)

Answer (score 2):

The ranges need to be the same size. Change B2 to B1 and it should work.

=COUNTIFS(A1:A15,">="&I1,A1:A15,"<="&I2, B2:B15, C1)

=COUNTIFS(A1:A15,">="&I1,A1:A15,"<="&I2, **B1:B15**, C1)